# How to sync facebook calendar?

Tags: lumia, calendars, facebook, lumia-520

I am using a Lumia 520. Recently I unsynced my Facebook account and synced it again to my phone. After this, I was not able to see my Facebook birthdays list. I checked the settings and it states Facebook Calendar as on. But I'm not getting any updates from Facebook in my mobile calendar. Can someone help me in updating the calendar with my Facebook birthday calendar?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect Facebook to Hotmail (Outlook.com). All your Facebook birthday calendar items will added to your Hotmail calendar.

1. Go to profile.live.com
2. Click connect (under your avatar or in the upper right corner)
3. Select Facebook and follow the steps.

Comment: how to do that. can you please elloborate it in details. so that i can add them.

Answer (score 0):

Login to [account.live.com](http://account.live.com) with the ID you've associated with the WP

1. Click on the Related Accounts.
2. Click Add Accounts (Connect to the accounts you use every day.)
3. Click Facebook and enter the credentials.

You're done. Give it some time to sync all the details including birthdays,profile photos, events etc.